# Can "trusty" and "trustworthy" be used interchangeably?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Such as:

1. "I'm going back to the clubhouse; there are trusty people there."
2. "I'm going back to the clubhouse; there are trustworthy people
   there."

---

### Trusty

- Definition: having served for a long time and regarded as reliable or
  faithful.
- Synonyms: *reliable*, *dependable*, **trustworthy**

### Trustworthy

- Definition: able to be relied on as honest or truthful
- Synonyms: *reliable*, *dependable*, honest

---

They appear to share many synonyms as well as the idea of reliability. The use of "trusty" is archaic and and seems almost comical now, but why is "trusty sidekick" acceptable, and why is "trusty person" not?

Comment: No. Go with example 2.

Comment: Please look up both words in a dictionary, and, if you still are uncertain, explain why you are still uncertain.

Comment: I suspect they were originally considered synonymous, but _trusty_ has lost its general meaning and is now only used to qualify servants.

Comment: No, at least not in American.  The common use of 'trusty' is for a prisoner in a jail who has been given some privileges in exchange for doing chores, so calling people trusty could easily be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitions you found tell the story well. **Trustworthy** has the connotation of truthfulness and someone to who would keep your secrets. **Trusty** has the connotation of someone or something you'd rely on to back you up in a fight.

*Trustworthy* is more cerebral or inward-looking; *trusty*, more practical or outward-looking.

Answer (score 0):

Note in the definition of trusty, it says "served for a long time" and "faithful." Therefore trusty is better suited to describe people in a "serving" position such a servant, sidekick (as you have questioned), etc. Whereas trustworthy is used to describe people who are generally reliable. Hope this helps